# Can't get cron job to STOP running

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, syslog

Trying to clean up a wordpress install that's been hacked and causing me headaches, think I've scrubbed it of nasty scripts...

but tailing syslog I see:

```
Jan 25 06:28:01 lester CRON[26721]: (git) CMD (/tmp/lib/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 25 14:58:01 lester CRON[26722]: (git) CMD (/tmp/lib/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 25 14:59:01 lester CRON[26787]: (git) CMD (/tmp/lib/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 21 13:37:01 lester CRON[26905]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/mysite/public/wp-admin/meta/1.sh)
Jan 25 15:01:01 lester CRON[26906]: (git) CMD (/tmp/lib/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

I'm confused by this, how is a log entry from jan 21 ending up here with jan 25 entries when I'm `tail -f`'ing syslog?

Also, there is no crontab for the `www-data` and no file `/var/www/mysite/public/wp-admin/meta/1.sh`

Comment: What kind of server are you running? A clean install seems like a safer option, especially if the intruder had shell access.

Comment: Are you sure it's an actual CRON job, and not a [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) hook?

Comment: @rnevius no I'm not sure, I assumed so as thats what its logged as. It's strange that log times from days ago are showing in todays logs, yes? I found a crontab for www-data days ago and deleted it. Yet the log continues to log this